# How to stop logging to console with selenium firefox driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When I create a firefox driver with a firefox driver service this is logged to the console: `1564067211938   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\minec\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.wCNOb94oHRE2"` The problem is the console when this happens gets effectively separated from my program and doesn't close when I close it with the stop button in visual studio. I also can't log anything to the console after that.

Is there any way to disable it?

Here is my code:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(geckoDriverPath.Replace(@"\geckodriver.exe", ""), "geckodriver.exe");
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to remove all logs except fatal error logs.

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(geckoDriverPath.Replace(@"\geckodriver.exe", ""), "geckodriver.exe");
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Fatal;
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "target" + File.separator + "browser.log");`
before the browser is being initialized 
ie. before 
`var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);`